# Wireless does not work after upgrade to Windows 8.1

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1-upgrade

I've recently upgraded my Lenovo g700 to Windows 8.1. After this, I cannot connect to my router via wireless (WPA2). Via a cable goes fine, and I can also connect to my mobile when set up as hotspot. I already updated the wireless device as described [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/dennis_schnell/archive/2013/08/31/windows-8-1-wifi-showing-quot-limitied-quot-or-quot-no-internet-access-quot.aspx) and tried the tips [here](http://everythingsurface.org/4-ways-to-solve-your-windows-8-1-surface-pro-wi-fi-issues) as well, but nothing works.

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Windows version is 64 bits, hardware id of wireless card Qualcomm Atheros is
PCI\VEN_1969%DEV_1090&SUBSYS_380317AA&REV_10 and CC_020000.

The router itself works fine for two other laptops (not windows 8) and worked fine with the lenovo when still on windows 8. Please elaborate on what you would want to know about the access point..

Comment: Have you installed the drivers that specifically support Windows 8.1 and/or tired the generic drivers?  If that fails to work we need specific wireless device information.

Comment: i have installed the Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter (Broadcom). i also tried the one from windows. Both are listed as compatible hardware.

Comment: @Marc Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? What's the hardware ID of the wireless card, as shown in the Device Manager?

Comment: If you can connect to your mobile phone as a hotspot then the device is working.  This means the problem is the access point itself.  Please provide more information about the configuration of the access point.  Provide all information in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

GOOD NEWS: IT FIXED!

I just got this problem fixed after I ran windows important update of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 for Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2 for x64-based Systems (KB2934520)

Installation date: ‎2015/‎2/‎23 下午 04:47

Installation status: Succeeded

Update type: Recommended

The Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 is a highly compatible, in-place update to the .NET Framework 4, 4.5 and 4.5.1. By using the .NET Framework 4.5.2 together with the C# or Visual Basic programming languages, you can write Windows Store apps. The .NET Framework 4.5.2 delivers better performance, reliability, and security than previous versions. After you install this update, you may have to restart your computer.

More information: 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2934520

Help and Support: 
http://support.microsoft.com

I've been struggled for this problem for the last two days after I accident upgrade to 8.1 (I upgrade twice and downgrade twice because the same wireless issue), I'm using wired internet for the last two days until now, I finally got the wireless back after I ran update and reboot, luckily I'm, hope you try this too!